# NSLog output different from debugger value

Tags: ios, nslog

Really strange problem here.

The statement

```
NSLog(@"currentSurveyID %d ", delegate.mySurvey.currentSurveyID);
```

incorrectly prints a value of 0

```
2014-06-08 18:02:58.400 SKPS-beta[4648:60b] currentSurveyID 0
```

However, when I look up the same variable in the debugger, the value is set to 825 (which is correct).

How is it possible that the NSLog output and debugger value are different?

`currentSurveyID` is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentSurveyID;
```

I have verified that the pointer value (address) of `delegate.mySurvey` is the same in the NSLog print statement and in the debugger, so I know that `delegate.mySurvey` is pointing to the correct object.

Comment: try replacing %d with %@ to see what object is printed, may not have an int value so defaulting to 0 possibly.

Comment: @aarti It's declared as an `NSInteger`. Using `%d` is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that `delegate` and `delegate.mySurvey` are both not `nil`? If either is `nil`, the log will show `0`.

Comment: Changing `%d` to `%@` prints `currentSurveyID (null)`. How can it be that currentSurveyID leads to a null value in the code but not in the debugger?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. I used an NSLog statement with %p and verified that the NSLog output matches the pointer value in the debugger.

Comment: Changing to `%@` gives `(null)` because `0` is the same as `nil` and `nil` values log as `(null)`.